# MS Word header and footer: set table width as percentage, then adjust to section margins

Tags: microsoft-word, headers, footers

My word 2016 document has several sections with different margins (orientation actually, but that's irrelevant), and a footer table with some information which changes occasionally. My problem is that I want to achieve all of the following:

1. Table width as a specific percentage of page width in all sections (eg. 100%)
2. All footers linked to previous section so that I only need to edit one footer when revising/reissuing the document.
   As you can imagine this is to make sure all footers are the same and I don't have to edit them in all sections every time.

However, what happens at the moment seems to be the following, which should be easy to reproduce:

1. I tick "link to previous" on the header/footer tab
2. Word sets a table width based on the first section in a chain of linked-to-previous sections (I would call it an "absolute" width)
3. That "absolute" width is applied in the subsequent sections, so if the first section in the chain is portrait, the landscape section uses less than the page width. And if the first section in the chain is landscape, the table exceeds the page width in portrait sections.

My own temporary workaround (which I'm chuffed about) is the use of Custom Properties inserted as Fields using [Allen Wyatt's excellent article](https://wordribbon.tips.net/T007794_Inserting_Custom_Properties_with_Fields.html) and it works reasonably well but, of course, there is a "but". The length of my properties is not always the same, and although the table naturally adjusts itself where necessary, it just doesn't always satisfy my team's sense of aesthetics, and I need to adjust it manually for all the sections anyway. So the workaround maintains the contents which is key, but can't be relied on for presentation.

Just as I am finishing this post, I realized I could probably tackle this by arranging the footer text with left/right Tabs rather than a Table, but my fellow users might struggle with this. I know there are bigger problems in the world than this, but any suggestions would be welcome.

PS this is my first post on this particular stack exchange and I just realized it trims greetings from posts!